# Lua: How to copy a line from a table to another table?

Tags: lua, copy, lua-table

I'm trying to copy the line of a table to another table. It's the first time I'm doing this so, logically, I just did

```
table.insert(table_destination[l], table_origin[l])
```

that works alright but when I modify the line in table_origin, table_destination changes also!!
I googled the thing and I came across some deep copy and shallow copy. I'm not experienced in this so I'm asking for help.

How can I copy one table line to another table so that I can operate changes to both table independently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables in Lua are passed by reference. You need to implement something like `shallowcopy` to create a new table with the same content as other table.

```
function shallowcopy(t)
    local t2 = {}
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        t2[k] = v
    end
    return t2
end

table.insert(table_destination[l], shallowcopy(table_origin[l]))
```

You can also implement a `deepcopy` function, which also copies all sub-tables recursively. Note: this can be dangerous because of possible cycles and/or not owned tables. This function assumes that the table *owns* all its subtables, not just references them.

```
function deepcopy(t)
    if type(t) ~= 'table' then
        return t
    end
    local t2 = {}
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        t2[k] = deepcopy(v)
    end
    return t2
end

table.insert(table_destination[l], deepcopy(table_origin[l]))
```

These two simple code snippets don't handle things like copying metatables, possible `__pairs` metamethod, tables used as keys, etc.

You can find better (or just more complex) implementations of table copying [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable) or [here](https://gist.github.com/Deco/3985043).

Comment: The listed `deepcopy` function is actually a shallow copy!